# How do I force browser not to convert 'comma' to 2C symbols using JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm changing current user's path through a function:

```
function setSomeValue(someValues) {
      var query = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < someValues.length; i++) {
        query += someValues[i] + ',';
      }
      if ('URLSearchParams' in window) {
        var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        searchParams.set("paramName", query);

        var newRelativePathQuery = window.location.pathname + '?' + searchParams.toString();
        history.pushState(null, '', newRelativePathQuery);
      }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm adding to user's location new words and want new location to be like this:

```
www.site.com?paramName=value1,value2,
```

But browser converts my commas into `%2C` so I get this:

```
www.site.com?paramName=value1%2Cvalue2%2C
```

What should be done to make pushing commas to URL possible?

---

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams such a good answer... xaxaxaxaaxaxaxa

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, if you don't know how this should be done - don't answer to me

Comment: @CBroe, check my edit

Comment: The encoding doesn't matter. The decoding usually happens automatically and if it doesn't there is the JS function `decodeURIComponent`.

Comment: @LabLab I have to admit the comment is quite funny.

Comment: It might be due to `URLSearchParams` and its `toString` method implementation - but we can’t know, because you failed to show us or even tell us what that actually is. If that is not deliberately encoding the comma, and the browser simply does it automatically - then there’s little you can do about that.

Comment: @CBroe maybe you know other way to generate new link? Any help appreciated!

Comment: @LabLab calm down man. Don't take everything so serious. Calling url encoding "such a disgusting thing" sounds pretty strange. Probably changing that particular part of your question would stop everyone from upvoting Ignacio's comment. :)

Comment: @LabLab the encoded version is the correct one. It HAS to be encoded. Imagine not encoding `&` and thus accidently adding a new parameter.

Comment: Before we could maybe figure whether there was another way to do this, you should figure out in which place exactly this encoding gets added to begin with. If `newRelativePathQuery` contains the encoded versions already, maybe they could be replaced back to normal commas. But if `history.pushState` does it, then “other ways” to create the URL itself won’t help you much.

Comment: @CBroe Checked console, `newRelativePathQuery` gets `%2C` before pushing to state

Comment: Well then replace them back to commas (research it please, if you don’t know how; for testing, a static string will do), and see if that “survives” being pushed to the history then …

Comment: @CBroe Something of a side note to the mechanical discussion here: I don't think the specification requires commas to be percent-encoded. `query` tokens are made of `pcahr` tokens, which consists of the options `unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims`. According to RFC 3986, it looks like a comma is a [`sub-delims`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2) token, which means it does not need to resort to a `pct-encoded` token.

Comment: @CBroe yeah, I'm gonna simply replace it. Thanks for directing me in the right way to solve it. Post it as an answer so I can mark it and vote up

Comment: @apsillers yeah you might be right on that one. The different handling in JS by `encodeURI` vs `encodeURIComponent` might have confused me in that regard.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams FYI, commas are valid in URLs according RFC 3986. This transformation is the WHATWG's [byte serialization specification](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-urlencoded-byte-serializer) being much more conservative than what the URL spec allows.

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis I havent been offenced, man. Just decided to remind that guy that this community isn't for memes.

Comment: 500K+ Reputation and 12K+ answers in this forum for @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. I am pretty sure he knows a thing or two about the community. I don't want to be "that" guy but generally I appreciate anything that could sound kind of funny and it isn't offending someone else. My comments aren't relevant to your question at all so I will stop. :) Have a good day my friend!

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis, Idk how he went so far in reputation if he doesn't even know about passing commas to url. You too!

Comment: @apsillers Thanks for that insight! I thought I was going crazy, but luckily it's only the Whatwg who've gone crazy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(copy & paste from several comments)*

It might be due to `URLSearchParams` and its `toString` method implementation - but we can’t know, because you have not shown us what that actually is. If that is not deliberately encoding the comma, and the browser simply does it automatically - then there’s little you can do about that.

If `newRelativePathQuery` contains the encoded versions already, maybe they could be replaced back to normal commas. But if `history.pushState` does it, then “other ways” to create the URL itself won’t help you much.

Since a debug output showed that `newRelativePathQuery` contains the encoded commas already, you can try and replace them back to commas, and see if that “survives” being pushed to the history then.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hacky, but here's one solution.  Let's say we want to use URL's searchParams.set() to set `ids=1,2,3,4` in our query string.

If you just do `url.searchParams.set("ids", "1,2,3,4")`, the URL will have `ids=1%2C2%2C3%2C4`.  To avoid that encoding, first set `ids=LIST_OF_IDS_PLACEHOLDER`, get the URL as a string, and then replace `LIST_OF_IDS_PLACEHOLDER` with `1,2,3,4`, like this:

```js
const myList = [1,2,3,4],
      url = new URL(document.location.href); // or however you get your URL object

url.searchParams.set("ids", "LIST_OF_IDS_PLACEHOLDER");
const newUrlString = url.toString().replace("LIST_OF_IDS_PLACEHOLDER", ids.join(','));

console.log(newUrlString); // this will include: ids=1,2,3,4
```